# Magento 1.9 Not able to create quote item

Tags: magento-1.9, php, quote, quoteitem, sales-quote

I have the following function inside my model.This checks for the device id(custom column in sales quote) in database and if found and the qoute item has same product id then just updates the qty or else create a new quote.When I use this,It simply is not going to else part.Here is my code.

```
  public function _create(array $data)
{      
    $postParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $product_id=$postParams['product_id'];
    $qty=$postParams['qty'];
    $deviceId=$postParams['device_id'];
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('device_id',  $deviceId);

foreach($collection as $item)
{

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($item->getEntityId());
$cartItems = $quote->getAllItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $items) {
$productId = $items->getProductId();
 $qtys = $items->getQty();
if($productId==$product_id){
    $qtys+=$qty;
    $items->setQty($qtys);
    $ks=$items->getQty();
    $items->save();
    }
    else {

        $productModel = 'hello';

    }
}


}



     echo json_encode(array('success' => $productId,'quoteObj' => $productModel)); die;

}
```

Please help.Thanks

Updated : This code now updates the quantity as well as create a new quote if i pass same product id and device id .If same pid and device id is passed ith should only update not create another one.

```
public function _create(array $data)
{      
    $postParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $product_id=$postParams['product_id'];
    $qty=$postParams['qty'];
    $deviceId=$postParams['device_id'];
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('device_id',  $deviceId);
        if ($collection->count()) {
            foreach($collection as $item)
{

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($item->getEntityId());
$cartItems = $quote->getAllItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $items) {
$productId = $items->getProductId();
 $qtys = $items->getQty();
if (! $quote->hasProductId($product_id)) {

$productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
   $productObj = $productModel->load($product_id);
    if (!$quoteObj) {
       // echo 'if'; die;
        $quoteObj = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote();
    }
    $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($store_id);
    $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);

    $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
    $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
    $quoteItem->setQty($qty);
    $quoteItem->setStoreId($store_id);
    $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
    $quoteObj->setStoreId($store_id);
    $quoteObj->collectTotals();
    $quoteObj->setCustomerId(null);
    $quoteObj->setDeviceId($deviceId); 
    $quoteObj->save();
    }
    else{
        $qtys+=$qty;
    $items->setQty($qtys);
    $ks=$items->getQty();
    $items->save();

    }

}

}
}
else{
$productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
   $productObj = $productModel->load($product_id);
    if (!$quoteObj) {
       // echo 'if'; die;
        $quoteObj = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote();
    }
    $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($store_id);
    $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);

    $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
    $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
    $quoteItem->setQty($qty);
    $quoteItem->setStoreId($store_id);
    $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
    $quoteObj->setStoreId($store_id);
    $quoteObj->collectTotals();
    $quoteObj->setCustomerId(null);
    $quoteObj->setDeviceId($deviceId); 
    $quoteObj->save();
}



     echo json_encode(array('success' => $ds,'quoteObj' => $ks,'quoteObj' => $dss)); die;

}
```

Comment: each times it satisfies the if condition???

Comment: I am able to update the qty

Answer (score 1):

to find if particular product is in quote

```
if (! $quote->hasProductId($product_id)) {
    // Product is not in quote so add your logic
}
else
{
   $item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product_id);
   $qty = $item->getQty();
   $item->setQty($qty);
   $items->save();
}
```

find is collection empty

```
if ($collection->count()) {
// Collection is not empty
}
else
{
}
```

After Update your code

```
public function _create(array $data)
{      
    $postParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $product_id=$postParams['product_id'];
    $qty=$postParams['qty'];
    $deviceId=$postParams['device_id'];
        $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('device_id',  $deviceId);
        if ($collection->count()) {
            foreach($collection as $item)
            {
                $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($item->getEntityId());
                $cartItems = $quote->getAllItems();
                if (! $quote->hasProductId($product_id)) {

                    $productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
                    $productObj = $productModel->load($product_id);
                    if (!$quoteObj) {
                       // echo 'if'; die;
                        $quoteObj = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote();
                    }
                    $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                    $storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($store_id);
                    $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);

                    $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
                    $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
                    $quoteItem->setQty($qty);
                    $quoteItem->setStoreId($store_id);
                    $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
                    $quoteObj->setStoreId($store_id);
                    $quoteObj->collectTotals();
                    $quoteObj->setCustomerId(null);
                    $quoteObj->setDeviceId($deviceId); 
                    $quoteObj->save();
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    $item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product_id);
                   $qty = $item->getQty();
                   $item->setQty($qty);
                   $items->save();
                   break;
                }


            }
        }
        else{
        $productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
           $productObj = $productModel->load($product_id);
            if (!$quoteObj) {
               // echo 'if'; die;
                $quoteObj = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote();
            }
            $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            $storeObj = $quoteObj->getStore()->load($store_id);
            $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);

            $quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
            $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
            $quoteItem->setQty($qty);
            $quoteItem->setStoreId($store_id);
            $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
            $quoteObj->setStoreId($store_id);
            $quoteObj->collectTotals();
            $quoteObj->setCustomerId(null);
            $quoteObj->setDeviceId($deviceId); 
            $quoteObj->save();
        }




     echo json_encode(array('success' => $ds,'quoteObj' => $ks,'quoteObj' => $dss)); die;

}
```

Comment: so this is working but how can i know weather collection has loaded ?$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('device_id',  $deviceId);

Comment: what do you mean by  collection has loaded ? if collection is empty it will not go through foreach @Melvin

Comment: collection is getting from device id.So if deviceid is not present,then collectionwill be empty? how will i check that ?so i can directly add device id and add product in quote

Comment: @Melvin find updated answer

Comment: Hi can you see my updated code

Comment: @Melvin find updated code

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in C:\xamppp\htdocs\...\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Item.php on line 422

Comment: @Melvin provide that line

Comment: public function representProduct($product)
    {
        $itemProduct = $this->getProduct();
        if (!$product || $itemProduct->getId() != $product->getId()) {
            return false;
        }

Comment: I just confused why it is going into both the if and else in one run

Comment: @Melvin Cause may be you `$collection` contains multiple quote means `device_id` can be of more than one quote

Comment: yes .So what can be done?

Comment: if you want to update quantity of one quote then filter it by id

Comment: how to get that?

Comment: Hi can you please help me to achieve this @gopal